# How to ping Windows 7 from Mac OS X on Home Network?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, mac, osx-lion

I'm fairly new to home networking. I've got a Windows 7 machine and Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) machine connected to the same home network via a wireless Netgear router. I can ping the Mac from the Win7 PC by default, but I can't go the other way around (ping attempts time out).

Can someone who is more enlightened in the area of networking explain how to enable pinging the Windows 7 machine from the mac? Naturally I'm ultimately hoping to do more than pinging, but this first step's hanging me up.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely your windows 7 firewall is blocking it, enter the command:

netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8 enable

to disable it back:

netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8 disable

Comment: Apparently that command is deprecated and 'netsh advfirewall firewall' is preferred? Not sure how to use the latter, but your suggestion worked anyway. Thanks!

Comment: I did'nt worked for me is there some command to enable icmp on mac